# Why doesn't Watir find script tag by src attribute

Tags: ruby, watir

Navigating to any page, I can review the scripts present with Watir:

```
b = Watir::Browser.new
b.goto "https://macys.com"
b.scripts.collect(&:src)
# => [ ..., "https://mathid.mathtag.com/d/i.js", ...]
```

The result is a large array of scripts, I've chosen one at random to find:

```
b.script(src: "https://mathid.mathtag.com/d/i.js").html
# => Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException: timed out after 30 seconds, waiting for #<Watir::HTMLElement: located: false; {:xpath=>"//script[@src='https://mathid.mathtag.com/d/i.js']"}> to be located; Maybe look in an iframe?
# ...
```

But it never finds any script this way. Why? How can I detect the presence without investigating the `scripts.collect(&:src)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watir is locating the element based on string matching what is present in the DOM. If you investigate the DOM, you'll see that the `https:` is not present, just the `//mathid.mathtag.com/d/i.js`. The browser driver translates that when queried about the attribute value to include the `https`, but Watir has no way to assume that when locating.

This will work:

```
browser.script(src: '//mathid.mathtag.com/d/i.js')
```

Comment: So, for this case, the way to reliably identify such a tag might be: `b.script(src: /\:\/\/mathid\.mathtag\.com\/d\/i\.js/i).html # => "<script type=\"text/javascript\" async=\"\" src=\"//mathid.mathtag.com/d/i.js\"></script>"`

Comment: @Sam it depends on what you are trying to do. I highly discourage using Regexp unless you have to, and if you do have to use Regexp it is recommended to "keep it simple" so long as that works for you (e.g. `/mathtag/`). We'll be updating Watir soon to allow simple regexp like that to only make one wire call instead of multiple.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the link you are trying doesn't have `https:`, The element you are trying to locate is this,

```
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="//mathid.mathtag.com/d/i.js"/>
```

So write this code, it would work.

```
p b.script(src: "//mathid.mathtag.com/d/i.js").html
```